# Foundation framework - house rules - are custom paddings okay?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I need to know if i'm recklessly disregarding the framework standards or
if this is the normal way to develop in foundation.

It is my first time using foundation, normally I use Framework 7 or Bootstrap.

**The CSS that is in question (note: these are custom html elements):**

```
#b-banner {
   background-color: #d6d6d6;
   width: 100 auto;
   height:300px;
}
#b-banner-content {
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-left: 6%;
}
```

**Take amazon for example:**
[amazon prime template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87NAw.png)

Can foundation do that by using rows/columns etc or is my CSS okay?

I can rewrite my website if it is wrong as I have only spent about 10 hours developing it.

**Thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Foundation styling quite simple, which is why I think it's a good starter when you want to create your own design. It allows you to rewrite everything you need quite easily. 
It's totally acceptable to override `padding / margin / etc`. You can also create your own components, based on another one if you want. You can load/unload components you need or not, to make the assets lighter, and add others JS plugins, and your custom css of course. 
You have a list of components, but if it doesn't answers your needs, just do it yourself.

And to answer your question, yes, you can do this with rows / columns / and everything, but it's not a problem to merge what you did with Foundation.